# Adding corrugated plastic panels adjacent to existing roof

Tags: roofing

[image]I have a 30 x 15 stick built shed with composition shingles over 1/2" sheathing. I would like to take 12 lineal feet off the end, remove the roofing and sheathing and install corrugated plastic to turn it into a greenhouse. How do I make that joint between the remaining composition roof and the corrugated plastic weatherproof?

Thanks

This is what I'm going to try. Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think you'd abut the two roofing types and overlay a flashing, lapping onto each 6 inches or more. The outcome would be similar to any hip or ridge.

Answer (score 0):

Plastic does not last more than a couple years. I have used about 3 types on my shed roof all failed. I "bit the bullet" and put in 1/4 plate glass , 2 X 4 ft.  panels. They have survived a hail storm which damaged our composition roof so badly that the insurance company replaced it.